# Getting error details from JHipster UAA microservice through gateway

Tags: spring, jhipster, microservices

Context: our app uses a JHipster generated gateway and UAA service (microservice architecture).
We're implementing blocking a user account after too many failed attempts.

The UAA service returns a 400 Bad Request when a blocked user tries to login, with a custom i18n code in the `error_description` field that can be used by the frontend to display the correct user error :

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "error.login.locked"
}
```

So far so good.

The issue happens when the login request is made **through the gateway**, because the answer is:

```
{
  "type" : "http://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Internal Server Error",
  "status" : 500,
  "detail" : "400 Bad Request",
  "path" : "/auth/login",
  "message" : "error.http.500"
}
```

There are **2 issues** here :

1. The HTTP status is 500. It's also the case when login fails because of a wrong password... 
   Is that the normal, expected behavior for the generated gateway ?
2. The `error` and `error_description` fields that are necessary for the frontend were lost passing through the gateway.

Is there a better way than to edit the gateway `authenticate` method, checking the `HttpClientErrorExceptionfor` and parsing an `OAuth2Exception` to get the details, raising a custom exception which is then handled by the `Exceptiontranslator` in order to conserve the needed fields? That seems a bit much, just to be able to preserve data sent by the service.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using - might not be the proper, optimal solution but it worked as I needed:

In the `OAuth2AuthenticationService`, I catch the exception (so that it doesn't bubble up as a 500 Internal Error)

```
 public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> authenticate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                                      Map<String, String> params) {
    try {
        [...]
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizationClient.sendPasswordGrant(username, password);
        [...]
        return ResponseEntity.ok(accessToken);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            // Throw the original exception from auth-service to keep its message (i18n code used by the frontend in my case)
            throw mapper.readValue(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), OAuth2Exception.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // If it's not a OAuth2Exception, let the error get thrown
            throw ex;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // If it's not a OAuth2Exception, let the error get thrown
        throw ex;
    }
```

In the `AuthResource.authenticate()` method, I catch these OAuth2Exception, wrap them in a custom AuthenticationFailureException class and let the `ExceptionTranslator` return the right object to the frontend (note the BadRequest Status and the message payload):

```
@ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationFailureException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleBadRequestAlertException(AuthenticationFailureException ex, NativeWebRequest request) {
    Problem problem = Problem.builder()
        .withStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
        .with("message", ex.getMessage())
        .build();
    return create(ex, problem, request);
}
```

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne : hope this can help you